# Where to define category of a website

Tags: html, website

When I am trying to open my website(I have a personal site) in my employer's computer. It gives me following error.

[image]

I guess some `meta tags` have these information. But which? And there must be some predefined values too, what are those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see there is a warning by your company's gateway or some kind of locally installed content filter. You need to contact your system administrator to whitelist your personal website. Depending on the processes in your company this can be a simple, a complicated or an impossible matter.

Comment: It has nothing to do with meta tags, then?

Comment: Highly unlikely.